# Trouble retrieving a .bak file using SQL Server in Amazon Linux

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have a SQL Server database running on a Amazon Linux machine and I want to create a backup of it. I am using the following query:

```
BACKUP DATABASE Database TO DISK = 'backup.bak';
```

This, in fact, creates a backup of my database in the `D:\rdsdbdata\BACKUP` folder. The only problem is that this folder does not exist on my machine. Trying to specify the path results in SQL attempting to save the backup in `D:\rdsdbdata\BACKUP` plus my folder, like this:

```
 BACKUP DATABASE Database TO DISK = '/home/work/backup.bak';
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Server EC2AMAZ, Line 1
> Cannot open backup device 'D:\rdsdbdata\BACKUP\home\work\backup.bak'. Operating system error
> The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server EC2AMAZ, Line 1
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Using another query, I can confirm that the `.bak` file actually exists in `D:\rdsdbdata\BACKUP` as it also increases the storage on the server. I need to retrieve the `.bak` file to my machine.

Is there any method to access the SQL Server disk to retrieve this file or a correct way to specify the path?

Comment: What's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` on your instance? Given what you've described so far it looks like an EC2 Windows based machine.

Comment: In RDS you would normally use AWS's custom `msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database` to perform backups directly to an S3 bucket. See: [Importing and exporting SQL Server databases using native backup and restore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using) which also includes IAM policy examples.

Comment: This is the output:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU20) (KB5024276) - 15.0.4312.2 (X64) 
 Apr  1 2023 12:10:46 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: So Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 != Amazon Linux. Have a read through the article I linked above and try using `msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database` instead.